# module ports - declaring input/inout/output

Tags: verilog

**If I want to use the following code inside a module what should be the directions of these variables?**

`always @(posedge clock)`

`begin`

```
a <= b;
b <= a;
```

`end`

*I tried using inout but inout doesn't work with reg.*

Answer (score -1):

Direction is chosen by where you need to make assignments to your signals. A `clock` usually gets assigned at the top level, so its value needs to come *in* to your module: `input`. `a` and `b` are being assigned inside your module, so you want their values to go *out* of your module: `output`.

```
module mine( input wire clock,
             output reg a,b);
```

Comment: but then if i use them as output, how would i change their values from the testbench?

Comment: You don't. The point of a testbench is changing inputs and observing outputs of your design.